# How do I change polygons form without lag?

Tags: android, google-maps, graphics

I have a Google map were I draw rectangles.

I have a draggable marker that makes the rectangle change is size as you move your finger.

I do polygon.remove and then create a new polygon with new points (one of the corners is the marker position and I calculate the others)

The resize is working, but the problem is that graphics are slow, you can see the polygon dissapear and reappear.

Is it because of a hardware limitation or there's another better approach?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Google Maps Android API, it is stated in the Polygon part [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polygons) that to alter the shape of the polygon after it has been added, you can call `Polygon.setPoints()` and provide a new list of points for the outline of the polygon.

So you must update the shape by calling `Polygon.setPoints()` rather than adding/removing it.

For more information, just check the link above.

Comment: I have tried this approach now but it's still laggy (maybe not so much). I will try on a better phone when I get the opportunity.

Comment: Maybe you are correct. try that in other phone because it might be a device issue.